# Append ID of current row with the image name in table of DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a table, let's say, inventory, and I'm storing details in the inventory table like ID (A.I), name, price, and imagepathname of the inventory in the table.

Now, I want to store the imagepath/name along with appending it with its ID, e.g: **photo/IN_02_imagename.jpg** in which photo is folder and I want to append IN which will be common with ID which I need to fetch.

How can I append the ID of that particular row in the table while inserting the data in the table?

```
$filetmp = $_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"];
$filename = $_FILES["logo"]["name"];
$filetype = $_FILES["logo"]["type"];
$logopath = "photo/".$filename;       // here i want ID getting appended with image name
move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$logopath);
```

Comment: Without inserting the data first you can't pre-acquire what the ID is going to be once it's inserted.

Answer (score 0):

**In your case,** Try to first get the MAX ID from the table using following query:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(ID) as ID FROM inventory");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$image_id = $result['ID'] + 1; // because next ID will be an increment of last one.
```

I am assuming that you are using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) to connect to your database and perform query operations..

and then use this $image_id in your image name to store in the database.

```
$logopath = "photo/IN_".$image_id."_".$filename;
```

Comment: @Neha would you mind accepting it as answer and also press the up arrow? :)